# How to remove optional quotes from argument to pgfkeys

Tags: pgfkeys

I am trying to define a pgf key handler  `name/.unquote and store in=\command` so that `{name="quoted string"}` or `{name=unquotedstring}` both work. That is, the net effect of `.unquote and store in` is to remove an optional outer string marks from the argument.

So far, I have been unable. From what I tried, everything breaks apart when using `\@ifnextchar`in the MWE below [I also tried to `\expandafter` at several stages, to no avail].

Can you help?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\def\remove@quotes@eov"#1"#2\pgfeov{#1}
\def\remove@eov#1\pgfeov{#1}
\def\maybe@remove@quotes#1\pgfeov{\@ifnextchar"%
    {\let\@next=\remove@quotes@eov}{\let\@next=\remove@eov}%
    \@next#1\pgfeov}

\pgfkeys{/handlers/.unquote and store in/.code=%
    {%
        \pgfkeysalso{%
            \pgfkeyscurrentpath/.code=%
                {%
                    \edef#1{\maybe@remove@quotes##1\pgfeov}%
                }%
        }%
    }%
}%


\pgfkeys{/faicon/.is family, /faicon/.cd,
    name/.unquote and store in=\shtcIconName,
    style/.unquote and store in=\shtcIconStyle,
}
\newcommand\shortcodefaicon[1][]{\pgfkeys{/faicon/.cd,#1}\faIcon[\shtcIconStyle]{\shtcIconName}}


\shortcodefaicon[name="apple", style=regular]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Side note, read the TeXbook for the reference to TeX programming *especially* on the topic of expandable/unexpandable commands.

Comment: Your ifnextchar will always see `\@next` and never the first character of `#1`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Damn! you're absolutely right, of course.

Comment: @user202729 I am confess that I have, although obviously not much sunk in...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use expl3 to make it a bit simpler. Assuming it is not a problem to convert the input to a string, and that if the first character is `"` then so is the last one.

```
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_if_eq:nnTF {x}
\cs_new_protected:Npn \assignRemoveQuotes #1 #2 {
    \str_if_eq:xnTF {\str_head:n {#2}} {"} {
        \str_set:Nx #1 {\str_range:nnn {#2} {2} {-2}}
    } {
        \str_set:Nn #1 {#2}
    }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\pgfkeys{/handlers/.unquote and store in/.code=%
    {%
        \pgfkeysalso{%
            \pgfkeyscurrentpath/.code=%
                {%
                    \assignRemoveQuotes{#1}{##1}%
                }%
        }%
    }%
}%


\pgfkeys{/faicon/.is family, /faicon/.cd,
    name/.unquote and store in=\shtcIconName,
    style/.unquote and store in=\shtcIconStyle,
}
\newcommand\shortcodefaicon[1][]{\pgfkeys{/faicon/.cd,#1}\faIcon[\shtcIconStyle]{\shtcIconName}}


\shortcodefaicon[name="apple", style=regular]

\end{document}
```

For educational purpose, a solution using LaTeX2e-programming style.

```
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\errorcontextlines=5
\def\remove@quotes@eov"#1"\myeov#2{\def#2{#1}}
\def\remove@eov#1\myeov#2{\def#2{#1}}
\def\maybe@remove@quotes{\@ifnextchar"%
    \remove@quotes@eov \remove@eov%
}

\pgfkeys{/handlers/.unquote and store in/.code=%
    {%
        \pgfkeysalso{%
            \pgfkeyscurrentpath/.code=%
                {%
                    \maybe@remove@quotes##1\myeov#1%
                }%
        }%
    }%
}%


\pgfkeys{/faicon/.is family, /faicon/.cd,
    name/.unquote and store in=\shtcIconName,
    style/.unquote and store in=\shtcIconStyle,
}
\newcommand\shortcodefaicon[1][]{\pgfkeys{/faicon/.cd,#1}\faIcon[\shtcIconStyle]{\shtcIconName}}


\shortcodefaicon[name="apple", style=regular]

\end{document}
```

Although it only really have "educational purpose" if you study the macro expansion rules properly and trace through the execution by hand. (most people don't *really* want to learn this.)

By the way, reusing `\pgfeov` proved to be an extraordinarily bad idea. (I should have guessed when the "mysterious error" came up.) So renamed to `\myeov` in the code.

Comment: Thanks a lot, especially for the educationally enhanced answer. I plan to go through it, but your comment about reusing \pgfeov is confusing...

Comment: @Koji It simply mean that the code of pgf relies on the user code **does not** contain `\pgfeov` to work correctly. Just try to rename `\myeov` to `\pgfeov` and incomprehensible errors pop up.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a PGFkeys solution that
uses a few helper macros (stored as other keys) that strip normal `"` or active `"` from their argument as well as a trivial macro that just grabs the whole argument.

Instead of needing to protect `\pgfeov` then with multiple braces, the original [`\pgfkeysdef` macro](https://tikz.dev/pgfkeys#%5Cpgfkeysdef) is used (which would have been used by `.code`) to hide that one `\pgfeov` from the PGFKeys parser.

Otherwise, we'll need three braces (or another helper macro like `\@firstofone`):

```
\pgfkeys{
  /handlers/.unquote and store in/.style={
    \pgfkeyscurrentpath/.code={{{% Eugh!
      \@ifnextchar"{\pgfkeysvalueof{/handlers/helper/unquote/.@cmd}}{%
        \expandafter\@ifnextchar\@activedblquote
                   {\pgfkeysvalueof{/handlers/helper/unquote active/.@cmd}}
                   {\pgfkeysvalueof{/handlers/helper/store in/.@cmd}}}##1\pgfeov
    \let#1\pgfkeys@temp}}}}}
```

---

Of course, if you use your own unpacker, there's no need to use `\pgfeov` here in the first place:

```
\def\removeNormalDblQuote"#1"\myeov{…}
\def\removeActiveDblQuote"#1"\myeof{…} % with active " of course
\def\donotremoveaDblQuote#1\myeov{…}
```

You just need to make sure that `\@ifnextchar` actually “sees” the first character of `#1`/`##1` … so don't use that `\@next` macro there, that won't work.

---

By the way, your definition would not store an unquoted argument in `#1` but the whole `\maybe@remove@quotes` spiel, too. That couldn't have worked either since `\faIcon` will need a fully expandable argument there.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{/handlers/helper/.cd,
  unquote/.code args={"#1"}{\def\pgfkeys@temp{#1}},
  store in/.code={\def\pgfkeys@temp{#1}}}
\begingroup % active " for babel user
  \catcode`\"\active
  \gdef\@activedblquote{"}%
  \expandafter
\endgroup\@firstofone{%
  \pgfkeys{/handlers/helper/unquote active/.code args=%
    {"#1"}{\def\pgfkeys@temp{#1}}}}
\pgfkeys{
  /handlers/.unquote and store in/.code=%
    \pgfkeysdef{\pgfkeyscurrentpath}{% \pgfkeysdef is what .code actually does
      \@ifnextchar"{\pgfkeysvalueof{/handlers/helper/unquote/.@cmd}}{%
        \expandafter\@ifnextchar\@activedblquote
                   {\pgfkeysvalueof{/handlers/helper/unquote active/.@cmd}}
                   {\pgfkeysvalueof{/handlers/helper/store in/.@cmd}}}##1\pgfeov
      \let#1\pgfkeys@temp}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{/faicon/.is family, /faicon/.cd,
    name/.unquote and store in=\shtcIconName,
    style/.unquote and store in=\shtcIconStyle}
\newcommand\shortcodefaicon[1][]{%
  \pgfkeys{/faicon/.cd,#1}\faIcon[\shtcIconStyle]{\shtcIconName}}
\shortcodefaicon[name="apple", style=regular]
\end{document}
```